# Convert date & time string to date & time format in Bash

Tags: string, bash, date, time

I have a log file which contains entries in this format:

```
Feb 15 14:28:37 [8085][8095] ssnotify.cpp:442:Send().....
```

How can I convert the date and time string to a date/time format so I can use it with other date/time commands within a bash script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "date" command for this task.

Example:

```
user@host:so$ date --date="Feb 15 14:28:37"
  jue feb 15 14:28:37 CET 2018
user@host:so$ date --date="Feb 15 14:28:37" +%s
  1518701317
```

If you do: "man date" you will see all the options about how to format the date as you wish.